# Summary report showing wrong currency for subtotals and grand total

Tags: reporting, multi-currency

I have an Opportunity report.  The accounts are set to USD.  The detail records on the report show the correct USD currency, but the subtotals show EUR.  Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: what is the running user's default currency?

Comment: The running user's default currency is USD.  When I recreated the report from scratch, it displays the currency correctly.  I have a feeling that the problem report was copied from a previous report where the default currency was not USD.

Comment: Michele! If it's still actual - did you try to change currency at right bottom corner?

Answer (score 0):

Check the bottom right corner (while in edit mode). You should see a currency dropdown box.
[image]